# Facebook Graph API Post Message in Hindi Language

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, multilingual

I would like to post message using Facebook Graph API in Hindi Language. Is it possible to support multi-lingual message post on user profile using Graph API? if yes, Please guide me proper api parameters needs to be included or API url.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/feed? Currently I am using this URL to post message but it's allow me to post English text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, AFAIK that is not currently possible. You can target/restrict your page posts to specific audiences, but creating the same post in multiple language "versions" as is currently possible via the UI, is not available via API yet.

Comment: Is there any server side code support to post message in other language? I have observe that 3rd party site allow us to post message in facebook with multiple language. I would appreciate you can guide us